# How to exclude elements inside a child-element from a selection without using children()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, parent-child

I have an element like so:

```
<div id="foo">
  <a href="#" class="some">click me</a>
  <div id="bar">
     <a href="#" class="some">click me too</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I need to select the `a` elements that are not inside `bar`. Problem is I can't use `children()`, because my `foo` is much more complex than above.

**Question:**
Is there a way to select "some" elements from a `foo` and explicitly excluding "some" elements from `bar`?

Comment: I am far from being a selector ninja ;-) Can someone explain me why $('a:not(#bar a)') wouldn't work ? Please.

Comment: hm... it does sound selector-ninja-esque :-)

Comment: $('#foo a.some:not(#foo #bar a.some)') would seem ninja-wannabe. Bon courage ;-)

Comment: @frequent: what if `bar` contains another `a` with a different class, other than `some`. Would you want that element part of the selection or not? I'm asking because the selector would be a little more complex then.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: No. I just need `a.some`, so all other link elements should be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the anchor elements may not always be a direct child of `foo` you can use the `filter()` method.

```
var anchors = $("#foo a").filter(function(){
    return !$("#bar").find(this).length;
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/v63tC/

Comment: ah. this looks good. `a` will not be a direct child of `#foo`, so this should help.

Comment: Ha i was also about to write the same.

Comment: Where in the solution is class `some` taken into account? As far as I can understand OP wants to select elements with the class of `some` from `foo` and explicitly exclude elements from `bar` with class of `some`. I would assume the class `some` would have to be part of the selector then.

Comment: Ok. This works. As per @FrançoisWahl comment, could you update `$('#foo a')` to `$('#foo a.some')`. Then it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) along with [$.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) to solve this

```
var $bar = $('#bar');
var items = $('#foo a.some').filter(function() {
    return !$.contains($bar[0], this)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TvLLk/)

Answer (score 1):

May be with a `>` direct child notation:

```
$('#foo > a')
```

You can omit some elem with `.not()`:

```
$("#foo a").not('#bar a').length;
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NSLb/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that your `#foo` element is considerably more complex than the example, is it safe to assume that it's not just direct descendants that you'll need to be selecting? If that is the case, I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#foo a.some').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents('#bar').length === 0;
});
```

That selects *all* `<a>` elements inside of `#foo`, then filters them down so that only those that don't have an ancestor with the `id` of `bar` on them are kept.

Comment: Where in the solution is class `some` taken into account? As far as I can understand OP wants to select elements with the class of `some` from `foo` and explicitly exclude elements from `bar` with class of `some`. I would assume the class `some` would have to be part of the selector then.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Ah, I think you're right - I missed that "some" was supposed to indicate it's a class, rather than just a vague approximation of a number of elements. They should be able to adapt the answer for themselves to add a class to the selector but I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (assuming the variable `foo` is your `#foo`)

```
var a = foo.find('> a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [child selectors](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for accomplishing your first task (getting all `<a>` elements from `foo`):

```
$('#foo > a'). ...
```